# Django Channels: Saving logged in user to session

Tags: django, django-channels

According to the [docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html#how-to-log-a-user-in-out):

> If you are in a WebSocket consumer, or logging-in after the first
> response has been sent in a http consumer, the session is populated
> but will not be saved automatically - you must call
> scope["session"].save() after login in your consumer code:

However, I am having some trouble implementing this.

I start by getting my user:

```
def login(form_data):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=form_data['username'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return "This account doesn't exist."
    password = form_data['password']
    if check_password(password, user.password):
        return user
    else:
        return "Incorrect Password."
```

And then following the directions like so:

```
user = login(form_data)
async_to_sync(login)(self.scope, user)
self.scope["session"].save()
self.send(text_data=to_json({
    'operation': 'set_user',
    'success': True,
    'message': "Loading User Data",
    'object': {'username': user.username}
}))
```

And it works to deliver the user to the page and set it up for the life of the consumer. However, it seems that the user is not being saved to the user's session, because when I reload the page, `self.scope['user']` once again returns an `AnonymousUser` object.

This is how I've got my asgi.py set up:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Likewise, navigating to other pages confirms that I am indeed not logged in. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `login` function is conflicting with `channels.auth.login`. Changing its name should fix it:

```
from channels.auth import login

def my_login(form_data):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=form_data['username'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return "This account doesn't exist."
    password = form_data['password']
    if check_password(password, user.password):
        return user
    else:
        return "Incorrect Password."

user = my_login(form_data)
async_to_sync(login)(self.scope, user)
self.scope["session"].save()
self.send(text_data=to_json({
    'operation': 'set_user',
    'success': True,
    'message': "Loading User Data",
    'object': {'username': user.username}
}))
```

Also the strings that are returned from `my_login` should be exceptions raised, right?

Comment: Good catch, but this function actually lives in a separate `.py` file in my code and is brought in like so: `user = auth_method(form_data)`. In reality I've tried several different ways of obtaining the user including `authenticate` and `.get()`. The login bit works, but it still won't save the user to the session.

Comment: I see. [This](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1096#issuecomment-619590028) might be relevant?

Comment: Hi @AdamStarrh. I didn't really answer the question but apparently if I get at least 2 upvotes I get half... I can promote a question you have to somehow give this back. You can reach me here if you'd like for me to do that.

Comment: I'm not worried about the rep, I was just hoping to grab some attention from someone closely familiar with the package. I've been working on this with someone else and we've replicated it in a fresh project, so I am pretty sure this is just a Channels bug. Thanks for taking time to look over my question!